# Conditional cast from 'AFError' to 'AFError' always succeeds

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

I'm using Alamofire and after I do the fetch request I'm handling the error with:

```
guard case let .failure(error) = response.result else { return }

if let error = error as? AFError {
    switch error {
            ...
    }
}
```

Problem:

In line `if let error = error as? AFError {` Xcode has a warning:

```
Conditional cast from 'AFError' to 'AFError' always succeeds
```

How can I Fix (preferred) or silence that warning?

I tried:

Removing it like this:

```
if let error = error {
```

but it says:

```
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AFError'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve already handled the case where you *don’t* have an error by returning. Thus, `error` is guaranteed to be a valid error object - it is not an optional, so you don’t need `if let` at all.